# Resources to qualify for AIME

Tags: usa, math-contests, resources

I am trying to qualify for AIME this year and get a score of at least $5$ or $6$. (If anyone doesn't know, AIME is the American Invitational Mathematics Examination. You need to get a decent score on the AMC (American Mathematical Contest) to qualify for taking the AIME. I was wondering if there were any books or resources that could be very helpful for the AMC.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: [Art of Problem Solving books](https://artofproblemsolving.com/store/list/all-products) *AND* [MAA problem solving books](https://www.maa.org/press/ebooks/problem-books) *AND* [Recommend Books at the IMO website](https://www.imomath.com/index.php?options=347). After exhausting all of these, [this google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=math+%22contest%22+%22books%22&filter=0) and [this google-books search](https://www.google.com/search?q=math+%22contest%22&tbm=bks&filter=0) might lead you to additional books.

Comment: @DaveLRenfro I already knew about aops, but thanks for everything else!

Comment: @DaveLRenfro Short as it is, that comment looks like an answer.

Comment: @DaveLRenfro there's a problem, when I try to use the MAA problem solving books, it says "Access denied".

Comment: @I am a person: Most of these books (MAA or otherwise) are like most books in general, in that one needs to purchase them. For freely available materials, you'll have to google a bit I suppose, as such materials are likely widely scattered over the internet at various people's homepages, in Stack Exchange answers, and other places. For someone to recommend very specifically something appropriate for you to buy (and assuming money available is very limited), we would need to know much more about your background and intentions, probably more than would be appropriate for Stack Exchange.

Comment: @DaveLRenfro oh ok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since no one has yet answered, as suggested in a comment I'm including the links I gave in a comment. Others are welcome to add to this (make sure they're not already included at the first three links), and maybe this should be a [Community Wiki answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts).

[Art of Problem Solving books](https://artofproblemsolving.com/store/list/all-products)

[MAA problem solving books](https://www.maa.org/press/ebooks/problem-books)

[Recommend Books at the IMO website](https://www.imomath.com/index.php?options=347)

After exhausting all of these, a google search for [math + "contest" + "books"](https://www.google.com/search?q=math+%22contest%22+%22books%22&filter=0) and a google-books search for [math "contest"](https://www.google.com/search?q=math+%22contest%22&tbm=bks&filter=0) will lead you to additional books.